# Smart PHP Session Handling/ Security

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've decided the best way to handle authentication for my apps is to write my own session handler from the ground up.  Just like in Aliens, its the only way to be sure a thing is done the way you want it to be.

That being said, I've hit a bit of a roadblock when it comes to my fleshing out of the initial design.  I was originally going to go with PHP's session handler in a hybrid fashion, but I'm worried about concurrency issues with my database.  Here's what I was planning:

1. The first thing I'm doing is checking IPs (or possibly even sessions) to honeypot unauthorized attempts.  I've written up some conditionals that sleep naughtiness.  Big problem here is obviously WHERE to store my blacklist for optimal read speed.
2. session_id generates, hashed, and gets stored in $_SESSION[myid].  A separate piece of the same token gets stored in a second $_SESSION[mytoken].  The corresponding data is then stored in **TABLE X** which is a location I'm not settled on (which is the root of this question).
3. Each subsequent request then verifies the [myid] & [mytoken] are what we expect them to be, then reissues new credentials for the next request.
4. Depending on the status of the session, more obvious ACL functions could then be performed.

So that is a high level overview of my paranoid session handler.  Here are the questions I'm really stuck on:

**I. What's the optimal way of storing an IP ACL?  Should I be writing/reading to hosts.deny?  Are there any performance concerns with my methodology?**

**II. Does my MitM prevention method seem ok, or am I being overly paranoid with comparing multiple indexes?  What's the best way to store this information so I don't run into brick walls at 80-100 users?**

**III. Am I hammering on my servers unnecessarily with constant session regeneration + writebacks?  Is there a better way?**

I'm writing this for a small application initially, but I'd prefer to keep it a reusable component I could share with the world, so I want to make sure I make it as accessible and safe as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been considering all comers to froma  technology standpoint:  plain-text, mysql (worried about locking), NoSQL ala Mongo, etc.  I'm open to all suggestions!

Comment: if every request you reissue new credentials for the next request, probably you'll break tab-based navigation. Also, there are companies with more than one internet connection (redundancy, load balancing) and so two requests of the same user may come from two different IP adresses.

Comment: I'm definitely taking into consideration the multiple IP issue by doing a sanity check on the IP for deny requests only, but leaving the man-in-the-middle check for session_id.

Comment: Also, I _believe_ that if I'm rotating the session_id, the cookie should update across tabs.

Answer (score 1):

**Writing to hosts.deny**

While this is a alright idea if you want to completely IP ban a user from your server, it will only work with a single server.  Unless you have some kind of safe propagation across multiple servers (oh man, it sounds horrible already) you're going to be stuck on a single server forever.

You'll have to consider these points about using hosts.deny too:

- **Security**: Opening up access to as important a file as hosts.deny to the web server user
- **Pain in the A**: Managing multiple writes from different processes (denyhosts for example)
- **Pain in the A**: Safely making amends to the file if you'd like to grant access to an IP that was previously banned at a later date

I'd suggest you simply ban the IP address on the application level in *your* application.  You could even store the banned IP addresses in a central database so it can be shared by multiple subsystems with it still being enforced at the application level.

Comment: Definitely agree on the hosts.deny thing.  Ok, that part is stricken.  I'll do it in the data repo.

Answer (score 0):

I. Optimal way of storing IP ACL would be pushing banned IP's to an SQL database, which does not suffer from concurrency problems like writing to files. Then an external script, on a regular basis or a trigger, may generate IPTABLES rules. You do not need to re-read your database on every access, you write only when you detect mis-behavior.

II. Fixation to IP is not a good thing on public Internet if you offer service to clients behind transparent proxies, or mobile devices - their IP changes. Let users chose in preferences, if they want this feature (depends on your audience, if they know what does the IP mean...). My solution is to generate unique token per (page) request, re-used in that page AJAX requests (not to step into a resource problem - random numbers, session data store, ...). The tokens I generate are stored within session and remembered for several minutes. This let's user open several tabs, go back and submit in an earlier opened tab. I do not bind to IP.

III. It depends... there is not enough data from you to answer. Above may perfectly suit your needs for ~500 user base coming to your site for 5 minutes a day, once. Or it may fit even for 1000 unique concurent users in a hour at a chat site/game - it depends on what your application is doing, and how well you cache data which can be cached.

Design well, test, benchmark. Test if session handling is your resource problem, and not something else. Good algorithms should not throw you into resource problems. DoS defense included, and it should not be an in-application code. Applications may hint to DoS prevention mechanisms what to do, and let the defense on specialized tools (see answer I.).

Anyway, if you get into a resource problems in future, the best way to get out is new hardware. It may sound rude or even incompetent to someone, but calculate price for new server in 6 months, practically 30% better, versus price for your work: pay $600 for new server and have additional 130% of horsepower, or pay yourself $100 monthly for improving by 5% (okay, improve by 40%, but if the week is worth $25 may seriously vary).

If you design from scratch, read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management first, then search for session hijacking, session fixation and similar strings on Google.